# Flow appending #! to callback URL

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Recently been having server issues on LinkedIn for their OAuth flows. However, from today (26th May) I am receiving a callback with the characters #! appended to the URL.

Sample url I am receiving is:

http://localhost:8081/v0/auth/linkedin/callback?code=AQTkd-3FtQEzWjr-S4hyB_9eCaMrfGY4XpnM3ovj3zehggqkQNBx__G58XPubS98Vej9gkWOPHyALY249AhN7MdgwHb6lJ1ncNlQ40_sSAG94wdk&state=eyJrZXkiOiJkZXZhcHAiLCJ0aGVuIjoiaHR0cDvL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgyL2xvZ2luLWNhbGxiYWNrP3RoZW49JTI1MkYifQ%3D%3D#!

I can't see what is adding the encode ==#! to the end of the state parameter?

Another integration with MS Graph API works correctly as expected.

Has anyone else seen this with LinkedIn integration recently?

Comment: Checking outbound call, state value is set to: `state=eyJrZXkiOiJkZXZhcHAiLCJ0aGVuIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgyL2xvZ2luLWNhbGxiYWNrP3RoZW49JTJGIn0%3D` but the return state is `state=eyJrZXkiOiJkZXZhcHAiLCJ0aGVuIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgyL2xvZ2luLWNhbGxiYWNrP3RoZW49JTJGIn0%3D#!`

Comment: a `#` is fragment identifier, and is only interpreted by the user agent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: i think `url.Parse()` should handle this fine (i.e. the #! will not be part of `parsed.Query.Get("state")`

Comment: Already had that with `parsedUrl, _ := url.Parse(r.URL.String())` and parsedUrl doesn't show the trailing fragment (#!). Setting a Location header and issuing a 302 redirect to that URL, the browser seems to maintain the fragment on redirection and breaks the site...?

Comment: Looks like the fragment is passed in browser regardless of URL/redirection parameters. Am using AngularJS on front end which seems to be failing as redirection from auth goes to localhost:8082/#! which can then be seen to be changed in the browser to juSt localhost:8082/!